# ASP.NET working with Data Sources

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am fairly new to ASP.net, but was tasked with creating a website to graph some data for our customer.

Is there a way to work with data pulled from a DataSource in ASP.net, before it goes into a table or graph?

I pulled a set of data from an SQL database, and I need to calculate the average of one of those columns to plot along with the data. I know I can do it in my select statement, but I am trying to minimize strain on our SQL server with my queries and put a bit more of the load onto our web server.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="nonDamped" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' ProviderName='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>' SelectCommand="<OMMITTED>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Of course you can perform calculations on values in .NET.  Have you tried anything?  If you have a list of objects you can select from it a list of values of a particular property on those objects and calculate the average of those values.

Comment: Which ASP.NET branch are you going to follow? ASP.NET MVC? WebForms?...If you go with ASP.NET MVC then you certainly create backend operations that do all the things you need....

Comment: @David I have them pulled out from an SQL server, so I can access the columns as Datafields in grid view, I just don't know exactly how I can perform calculations in them.

Comment: @e4rthdog I currently have it in webforms.

Comment: @GarrettRietveld: How are you getting the data from SQL?  For example, if you select from an Entity Framework data context (or even old Linq to SQL) then you would just use a `.Select()` to get the list of numeric values and average those values.  (There may even be a `.Average()` in Linq?)  It's not clear where you're stuck, maybe you can show some code?

Comment: @David I added my line for creating my dataSource. Its set up with OLEDB. There isn't too much else in my code yet other than just graphing the data.

Comment: @GarrettRietveld: Oh, you're using declarative data sources :-/  That's going to make this... worse.  I haven't touched that stuff in probably 10 years, wish I could help you.  If you get a chance to walk through an MVC and Entity Framework tutorial, do yourself a favor and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object of the DataTable class or the DataSet class to store the results from your select statement. Then you can traverse though the data using the [row] [column] index properties of the objects.
eg.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter("Select Query",connectionstring);
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
int x=Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[RowNumber][ColumnNumber]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes u can calculate average. when u pull data from database and storing that to  dataset or datatable . declare few variables in code file and assign value to them from dataset or datatable. the perform the calculation and finally assign value of those variables to table or graph. eg.

```
Datarow dr = ds.table[0].Rows[0];

int64 x =convert.toint64(dr["YourValue"].tostring());
int64 y =convert.toint64(dr["YourValue"].tostring());
```

now some calculation

```
decimal z= (x/y)*100
```

then assign this (Z) to table or graph as u wish